# why d is getting replaced with @ in this code

Tags: javascript, regex

I am replacing @ symbol in email with - .

```
var authdata = JSON.parse(getCookie("authData"));
var namespace = authdata.Email.replace('@','_');
namespace = namespace.replace(/./, '_');
namespace = namespace.replace(/\./g, '_');
```

namespace comes as  '_emo_duosoftware_com'

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` in regex will match any single character except newline.

The problem is here

```
namespace.replace(/./, '_');
```

To replace decimal point symbol, escape it by preceding it with backslash.

The two statements can be combined

```
var namespace = authdata.Email.replace(/[@.]/g, '_');
```

Match `@` or `.` as many times as possible(`g` flag) and replace by `_`.

Comment: @Sajeetharan Probably you were using or should use the string replace `.replace('.', '_')`

Answer (score 1):

It's because of this regex:

```
namespace = namespace.replace(/./, '_');
```

It's a non-global wildcard, see here: http://regexone.com/lesson/wildcards_dot